# Remove snippets of JS from core

Tags: functions, customization, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I can see these bits of code in the source in my wp install:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wp-playlist-current-item">
    <# if ( data.image ) { #>
    <img src="{{ data.thumb.src }}" alt="" />
    <# } #>
    <div class="wp-playlist-caption">
        <span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-title">&#8220;{{ data.title }}&#8221;</span>
        <# if ( data.meta.album ) { #><span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-album">{{ data.meta.album }}</span><# } #>
        <# if ( data.meta.artist ) { #><span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-artist">{{ data.meta.artist }}</span><# } #>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wp-playlist-item">
    <div class="wp-playlist-item">
        <a class="wp-playlist-caption" href="{{ data.src }}">
            {{ data.index ? ( data.index + '. ' ) : '' }}
            <# if ( data.caption ) { #>
                {{ data.caption }}
            <# } else { #>
                <span class="wp-playlist-item-title">&#8220;{{{ data.title }}}&#8221;</span>
                <# if ( data.artists && data.meta.artist ) { #>
                <span class="wp-playlist-item-artist"> &mdash; {{ data.meta.artist }}</span>
                <# } #>
            <# } #>
        </a>
        <# if ( data.meta.length_formatted ) { #>
        <div class="wp-playlist-item-length">{{ data.meta.length_formatted }}</div>
        <# } #>
    </div>
</script>
```

I've tried to dequeue but it doesn't stop loading.
I added:

```
function my_dequeue_script() {
 wp_dequeue_script( 'mediaelement' );
 wp_dequeue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
 wp_dequeue_script( 'wp-playlist' );
 wp_dequeue_script( 'wp-embed' );
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

and

```
function my_deregister_scripts(){
    wp_dequeue_script( 'mediaelement' );
 wp_dequeue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
 wp_dequeue_script( 'wp-playlist' );
  wp_deregister_script( 'wp-embed' );
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_deregister_scripts' );
```

Neither of them removes the scripts furthermore I'd like to remove those snippets of code, I think they're for audio, I'm not going to use it so how can I remove those using the functions.php?
What are the implications of removing those if I don't ever use audio files?

Comment: Looking at core code the _only_ time these scripts should be output are if you're using the playlist shortcode, which requires them. So if they're appearing then you're using them somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I used the following code and the bits of code no longer appear:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_my_action' );
function remove_my_action(){
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
    remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
}
```